# C++ String.h Char Tables cutting-off word without strstr

Tags: c++, char, operators, string.h

I need help with C++ `<string.h>` char tables.... How to cut word from sentence, using "`*`" operator, with no `strstr`? For example: "StackOverFlow is online website". I have to cut off "StackOverFlow" and leave in table "is online website" using operator, with no `strstr`. I couldn't find it anywhere.

Mostly like:

```
char t[]

int main
{
  strcpy(t,"Stackoverflow is online website");

  ??? 
  (Setting first char to NULL, then strcat/strcpy rest of sentence into table)

}
```

Sorry for English problems/Bad naming... I'm starting to learning C++

Comment: Am I understand you right? You need to cut off part of c-string and store it in the same variable? Is there any reason against strstr in this case? You always can implement it by yourself, but it's like a bicycle reinvention

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Explain better what you need, please.

```
char szFirstStr[] = "StackOverflow, flowers and vine.";
strcpy(szFirstStr, szFirstStr + 15);
std::cout << szFirstStr << std::endl;
```

Will output "flowers and vine".

Using c strings is not good style for C++ programmer, use `std::string` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is obviously syntactically incorrect, but I guess you are aware of that.

Your variable `t` is really a char array and you have a pointer that points to the first character of that char array, like you have a pointer that points to the first character of your null terminated string. What you can do is to change the pointer value to point to the new starting point of your string.

You can either do that, or if you indeed use an array, you can copy from the pointer of the new starting point you wish to use. So if the data you wish to copy resides in memory pointed to by:

```
const char* str = "Stackoverflow is an online website";
```

This looks like the following in memory:

```
                      Stackoverflow is an online website\0
str points to:      --^
```

If you want to point to a different starting point you can alter the pointer to point at a different starting location:

```
                    Stackoverflow is an online website\0
str + 14 points to: --------------^
```

You can pass the address of the "i" to your `strcpy`, like so:

```
strcpy(t, str + 14);
```

Obviously it is not certain that you know the size to cut off without an analysis (the 14), what you might do is search through the string for the first character following a white space.

```
// Notice that this is just a sample of a search that could be made 
// much more elegant, but I will leave that to you.
const char* FindSecondWord(const char* strToSearch) {
    // Loop until the end of the string is reached or the first 
    // white space character
    while (*strToSearch && !isspace(*strToSearch)) strToSearch++;
    // Loop until the end of the string is reached or the first
    // non white space character is found (our new starting point)
    while (*strToSearch && isspace(*strToSearch)) strToSearch++;
    return strToSearch;
}

strcpy(t, FindSecondWord("Stackoverflow is an online website"));

cout << t << endl;
```

This will output: *is an online website*

Since this is most likely a school assignment, I will skip the lecture on more modern C++ string handling, as I expect this has something to do with learning pointers. But obviously this is very low level modification of a string.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner why make it harder then it really have to be?

Use std::string

and

substr()
[Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)